# Moving colors to separate CSS file isn't working

Tags: html, css

This is driving me nuts. I have all of my colors in one CSS file, and all of the other properties in another. Everything works fine except for this part.

```
.jwr_post_format:after {
border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
border-right-color: #ffffff;
border-width: 8px;
margin-top: -8px;
}

.jwr_post_format:before {
border-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0);
border-right-color: #cccccc;
border-width: 9px;
margin-top: -9px;
}
```

When it's all together like this, it works fine. But when I take the `border-color` and `border-right-color` and put it in another css file, the elements do not show (the colors disappear).

What's going on here?

Comment: Are you sure you have the other stylesheet linked in the between the head tags in the html document, no typos, etc? Like so...  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

Comment: And yes, both stylesheets are linked properly. I have dozens of other styles all working properly between the two.

Comment: Is the second stylesheet loaded after the first one? Also, do you have a link to the working project or a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in wich css files are executed is important.
putting part of the css in another file may affect your general heaviour...

Answer (score 0):

Could be that `:before` and `:after` do not specify any content. I assume you specify the `content` tag elsewhere in the CSS, but if you did not that would be a definite problem.